# Scripted Jenkins file for maven package

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing a `Jenkinsfile` for Maven package by using scripted syntax

```
node{     
    stage('Checkout')             
          git url:'<gir url>',branch: 'master    
    stage('build')      
          sh 'mvn clean package'    
}
```

my problem is how to declare the maven version in above Jenkinsfile (in scripted syntax only)

Answer (score 1):

I just completed a major Jenkins Pipeline/Maven implementation with the Pipeline Maven Integration plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-maven.

It let's you leverage Maven Tool configuration when you run Maven commands in your pipeline.